# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'jobTreeReducers' before initialization

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, commonjs, ecmascript-2020

In our application we are using Angular(version 10) and ngrx(version 7). My app was running fine till I changed the tsconfig. I changed the below property:

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

**to**

```
"module": "es2020"
```

From then I started getting the below error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'jobTreeReducers' before initialization
```

Following is the folder structure for the error raised module

[image]

The job-tree-store.module.ts is

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { EffectsModule } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { jobTreeReducers, JobTreeEffects } from "./index";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        StoreModule.forFeature('jobTree', jobTreeReducers),
        EffectsModule.forFeature([JobTreeEffects]),
    ]

})
export class JobTreeStoreModule {}
```

I imported that and using in the App Module.

Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks...

Comment: This is typically a circular dependency problem.

Comment: @Bergi, We put all the store stuff into a module and importing that into the app module. Can you please help how this circular dependency has occured?

Comment: Same, had this issue and looked for a circular dependency -> found and fixed it. Thanks @Bergi

Comment: Can you please give an example of what kind of circular dependency should I look for @Deitsch Thanks!

Comment: I can't recall 100% anymore, but 2 files were importing parts of each other